# CBLite (couchbase lite) iOS platform

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I’m pretty new with CBLite, I inherited a code that heavily uses FTS and all looked good until we discovered if we search for some words containing dash `-` like `A-Something` the query execution takes 4-5 times longer than usual. I couldn’t figure out why this happens and how I could find a solution on my end (mobile CBLite for the iOS platform).

Also, the search for some words that contain parenthesis `(`, won't work at all, the result is always empty for those items.

Comment: Hey @Cam: Our SQLite expert answered this question, in the Couchbase forum, Nov 23, the same day you posted it.

Comment: Yes, I received what I was looking for. I looked into SQLite FTS query language docs. and it gave me some insights into how Tokenizer and reserved keywords work.

Answer (score 0):

Jens Alfke, an architect at Couchbase, says:

It’s been some years since I last worked on the FTS code in CBL but here are some things that might help:

- I don’t think the tokenizer (the thing that breaks strings into
  words) considers a “-” part of a word. So “foo-bar” would be indexed
  as the two words “foo” and “bar”, and a search for “foo-bar” would
  just be looking for those two words. I could be wrong though; you
  could so some experiments to make sure.
- If the above is true, then “A-Something” would be tokenized as “A” and “Something”, and “A” would be ignored when indexing because
  it’s a “stop-word”, one of the super common words like “the” and “he”
  that get tossed out. That means the query would be searching for just
  “Something”.
- Parentheses are definitely not considered part of a word. So parens in a document string are ignored. Parens in a query will
  perform grouping of logical expressions as described in the SQLite
  FTS query language docs 1.